# How do I customize the way Emacs prints out certain keys and key sequences?

Tags: key-bindings, unicode, help, customization

For example, I want <kbd>Control</kbd> key to be displayed not as <kbd>C</kbd> but as <kbd>⎈</kbd> (U+2388 HELM SYMBOL) in the minibuffer.
Trying to personalize my Emacs and display all function keys as ISO symbols. And sequences to be displayed as something like `⎈ + x, ⎈ + f`.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. There is a function `key-description` that takes a list or vector of keys and returns a string that describes them. This is used by the built-in help facilities such as `describe-key` and `describe-function` to display information about key bindings. It calls `single-key-description` on each element of the input list. Both of these are written in C rather than Lisp, but you could in principle override both of these to do what you want by adding advice to them.

`key-description` is even called by the Info system to render the correct key bindings in the documentation, even once the user starts customizing them.